# sed regex find and delete string globally

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following (working) regex:

```
UNUSED([^,}]+)\}|,\s?UNUSED([^{]+)|UNUSED([^{]+),\s?|UNUSED([^{]+)
```

I run the command

```
sed 's/UNUSED([^,}]+)\}|,\s?UNUSED([^{]+)|UNUSED([^{]+),\s?|UNUSED([^{]+)//g' < index.css > newfile
```

but the newfile still has all the patterns in which should have been removed. What I am doing wrong?

index.css incl. regex:

http://regexr.com/3agmm

Comment: There is no such thing as a "working regex". Different tools support different regexp syntax/functionality/extensions/delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are using an extended POSIX regex. You you need to pass `-r` to sed to tell it to use extended POSIX regexes.

Also note that the capturing groups you are using can be omitted:

```
s/UNUSED[^,}]+}|,\s?UNUSED[^{]+|UNUSED[^{]+,\s?|UNUSED[^{]+//g
```

Of course you can also use a basic POSIX regex, then without the `-n` option:

```
s/UNUSED[^,}]\+}\|,\s?UNUSED[^{]\+\|UNUSED[^{]\+,\s?\|UNUSED[^{]\+//g
```

Comment: You are welcome! I wonder why it is not possible to specify the regex language on that site you used for the example.

Comment: Couldn't the parentheses just be removed? They don't seem to be used for grouping, and I see no backrefs. Oh, and `}` doesn't need to be escaped in basic regex syntax unless you want the metacharacter. (By the way, on the list of realmanly boneheaded things that can be done in sed, basic regex syntax is among the most harmless. :D The buffers must dance!)

Comment: @Wintermute The capturing groups are used for alternative matches, like `(a|b)` ...

Comment: Those are all outside the parentheses. The stuff inside them is all of the form `[^,}]\+`, which would be fine on its own. Or am I blind?

Comment: Alternatives are quite complex: `([^,}]\+\)}\  <-a   |,\s?UNUSED\([^{]+\ <- b)` .. However, I would not say that the regex can't be optimized. I never really digged into it..

Comment: Hold on, that's not a single capturing group. In `\([^,}]\+\)}\|,\s?UNUSED\([^{]+\)` there are two capturing groups, both of which capture `[^,}]\+`.

Comment: @Wintermute Yes, the capturing groups can be omitted. Alternation works even without them.. (Didn't knew that)

Comment: `s/UNUSED[^,}]\+}\|,\s\?UNUSED[^{]\+\|UNUSED[^{]\+,\s\?\|UNUSED[^{]\+//g` is the straightforward basic regex transformation, I think (other than the parens: `?` needs escaping, and there was an unescaped `+` in the second alternative).